# Rails 3 app crashes after Sunspot installation on development env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I used  [this guide](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/README.md) to install Sunspot. I successfully run folowing commands:

```
**Add to Gemfile**:

gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr' # optional pre-packaged Solr distribution for use in development
Bundle it!

bundle install
**Generate a default configuration file:**

rails generate sunspot_rails:install

**If sunspot_solr was installed, start the packaged Solr distribution with:**

bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start # or sunspot:solr:run to start in foreground
```

After that my website crashed. I tried these things:

Restarted passanger with:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

then again `bundle install`

I am getting this error :

```
Could not find mini_portile-0.5.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

My app link : http://darbs.ecotechno.lv/

Comment: Is mini_portile in the Gemfile?

Comment: @Baloo Yes, I  have. I reinstalled it, but no luck there. Also restarted webserver. No luck.

Comment: @Baloo But does sunspot work with mysql database ? Because I have it.

Comment: If this is running in production have you tried running bundle install --deployment?

Comment: Sunspot will work with a mysql database but indexes within solr

Comment: @Baloo bundle install --deployment worked

Comment: Great, but you shouldn't be using sunspot:solr in production

Comment: @Baloo Why is that ? How can I restrict it ?

Comment: As it says `gem 'sunspot_solr' # optional pre-packaged Solr distribution for use in development` it's only designed to be used in development you should really install [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) properly in production

Comment: @Baloo after this I  found that my app now loads pretty slow.